# How to run all functions in Module based one global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

```
Module.py:

def a_1()
 print("a_1") if global_var !=True:
def a_2()
 print("a_2")if global_var !=True:
def a_n()
 print("a_n")if global_var !=True:
```

global_var =True

Program

```
from Module import *
global global_var =True
a_1() # should not print anything
```

If global_var == True then all function in module should be show as PASS( dont print)

How to control all function in a module by a global var in python

- i really dont want put the condition in every function - i want to one technique all function running controlled by global var

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] read about [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then [edit] the question.

Comment: Its unclear why you would want this. How would you do it in a different language?

Comment: No global variable will make the functions behave in a way contrary to how they are defined. Maybe each function should be defined like `def a_1(): if global_var: print("a_1")`?

Comment: You can monkeypatch the print function in the Module.py but I would rather not.

Comment: You can generally suppress output by modifying "sys.stdout" and maybe "sys.stderr". You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score -1):

You could just try doing an if statement

```
global_var = True
def a_1():
    print("a_1")
def a_2():
    print("a_2")
def a_n():
    print("a_n")
if global_var:
    a_1()
    a_2()
    a_n()
```

Comment: I thought they were meant to show as PASS according to the question. You should probably ask for clarity before answering, as it's not clear what OP really wants.

Comment: there are 100 scripts to modify this this way.

Comment: instead of avoid duplicate of code - i want to use some technique to slove this issue

Comment: You can just try adding an if statement in those.